# recipient of agent depends on analyse in OBIEE

Tags: obiee

I am using OBIEE 11g.
I have an anlyse that show the list of all employees that have more then 30 days absences. In the list I have also the email addresses of those employees.

I want to create an agent that send a email to all employees of the list in my analyse, using the email addresses in the list.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Put the same analysis as a conditional analysis for the agent, then go to the "Recipients" tab and check "Get Recipients from the Analysis used in the Agent Condition" and then choose the column which contains the email. Done.